# Simple $R$-module equivalent statement

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

I am trying to show that the two statements are logically equivalent.

a) $X$ is a simple $R$-module.

b) For any $x , y \in X$, $x,y \neq 0$ , there exists $r \in R$ such that $rx = y$.

In other words,  I am trying to show that $X$ is a simple $R$-module $\iff$ For any $x , y \in X$, $x,y \neq 0$ , there exists $r \in R$ such that $rx = y$.

Here $R$ is a commutative ring. Furthermore, by a simple $R$-module I mean a non zero module that has non proper submodules.

I am very new to the study of modules so any push in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: Hint for the harder direction: given $x\neq0$, one has that $Rx$ is a submodule.

Comment: When you say harder direction, you mean b to a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a)\to (b)$: Let $0\ne x,y\in X$. Then $Rx=\{rx: r\in R\}$ is a submodule of $X$. This submodule is nonzero, as it contains the element $x$. Since $X$ is simple it follows that $Rx=X$, and in particular $y\in Rx$.

$(b)\to (a)$: Let $Y$ be a nonzero submodule of $X$. So take any $0\ne y\in Y$. We will show that $Y=X$. Let $x\in X$. By assumption there is some $r\in R$ such that $x=ry$ (if $x=0$ you can take $r=0$), so in particular $x\in Y$.